# PHP `iconv` not working inside a Wordpress site

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function to convert accented characters to their non-accented correspondents. For example, "ç" becomes "c", "é" becomes "e" and so on...

For example, this code converts the word "ação" to "acao":

```
<?php
    $filename = "ação";
    $filename = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $filename); // convert latin characters
    echo $filename; // shows "acao"
```

Check the code above here: https://ideone.com/tv5C03

However, running the same function inside my Wordpress site, it shows:

> a??o

How to fix this?

---

### Edit

I'm using `iconv` inside a custom function of the plugin [WP All Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import):

[image]

Comment: Where and how are you using it?

Comment: I'm using it inside a custom function of the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: Found a solution

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I need to insert this instruction BEFORE `iconv`:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8");
```

Thus, the conversion is done correctly (in my case, because my site is in `pt_BR`):

```
<?php
    $filename = "ação";
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8"); // fix the locale
    $filename = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $filename); // convert latin characters
    echo $filename; // shows "acao"
```

Correct result:

> acao